# what are content scripts in chrome inspector

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector, content-script

While this could be a very basic thing, I can't seem to find an answer to this one. I see a lot of discussion about `content scripts`. When I open `web inspector` in `chrome`, and select `sources`, I see a tab called `content scripts`. I see a couple of random numbers and a number of scripts and I can't seem to figure out what these are.
How are these being shown? where are these coming from? I can't see my server serving any of these.

Comment: Are they from your installed extensions? I know that from developing an extension the injected js files are referred to as content scripts.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Google Chrome, [*content scripts*](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) are JavaScript files that are part of browser extensions.  They operate on the web page much like regular javascript does, but from a protected scope (Google calls it an "Isolated World").

Content scripts have a few more privileges than ordinary javascript and, for that reason, content-script JS and page JS cannot ordinarily interact with each other.

When looking at that ***Content Scripts* tab**, you will see both the scripts added by any extensions (or by [userscripts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) which are compiled into extensions in Chrome), and also content scripts that are built-in parts of the browser, specifically the API that extensions can use.

[image: Content script listing]

You can match extensions to those "random numbers" by opening the extensions tab (`chrome://chrome/extensions`), and activating `Developer mode`:

[image: Matching extensions]

Answer (score 0):

If you keep seeing the "Content Scripts" tab only, it is because your tools pane is too narrow. Click the ">>" icon to find the Page tab. For ordinary websites, you will want the Page tab active. "Content Scripts" is used for writing browser extensions.